# Python schedule "Time is freezing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, schedule

I am using **schedule** to do functions that work with the real-time `datetime.datetime.now()`.
But when calling the function  `datetime.datetime.now()` i always get start time **schedule** script.

Example:

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime


schedule.every(2).minutes.do(print, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Example result:

```
28-04-2021 19:59
28-04-2021 19:59
28-04-2021 19:59
28-04-2021 19:59
```

Does anyone have any ideas how one can get real time during the execution of the **scheduler**?

```
Python => 3.8
schedule => 1.1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the return value of `now()` gets saved in memory. Pass a lambda or function to ensure it is dynamically calculated:

```py
import schedule
import time
import datetime

schedule.every(2).minutes.do(
    lambda: print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I still have a lot to learn and a lot to understand. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I make similar mistakes from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

This is because value of `now` is already loaded into memory.

Try this

```
    import schedule
import time
import datetime

schedule.every(2).minutes.do(print, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I thought so too, and tested this option. the behavior is the same.